# Algebraic tricks like componendo dividendo

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I wanted to know all the operations that can be performed if say-
a/b=c/d
And 
Also on 
a/b=c/d=e/f
Where a b c d e and f are various variables.

One is if we add and subtract 1 we get

(a+b) /b=(c+d) /d......

And (a-b) /b......

And by dividing we get the componendo dividendo theorm.

But recenty i saw my book using the formula-

a/b=c/d=e/f=(a+c+e) /(b+d+f)

How does this be proved?

And also i saw a similar Formula in which squaring was involved...

I know i am giving a very vague picture but please provide me with all such operations that can be done in these situations and there derivations also please.

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo#Comment_on_the_proof?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably too many useful transformations, even of moderate complexity, to list them all. I don't know about that part of the question.

If $a/b=c/d=e/f=r$ then $a=br$, $c=dr$ and $e=fr$. Add these equations to get $$(a+c+e)=r(b+d+f).$$

From this $r=(a+c+e)/(b+d+f)$.

Comment: After "From this" I think you want to divide in that formula rather than multiply.

Comment: @coffeemath I guess I didn't press the / key all the way.

Comment: Yes, seemed it must have been a typo... I'll remove this and the other comment if you like.